# Store quantile ranges in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written the following code to grab the quantile ranges and store it in a new column:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data_train['paper_mentions'])
df_temp['q_dr_du'] = pd.Series(pd.qcut(df_temp['paper_mentions'], q=4, duplicates='drop'))
df_temp['q_rank'] = pd.Series(pd.qcut(df_temp['paper_mentions'].rank(method='first'), q=4))
```

I'm creating 2 different columns for 2 types of ranges. Output below:
[image]

I want the actual quantile ranges stored in a new column, which is similar to what I'm storing in `df_temp['q_dr_du']`. I've had to use `duplicated='drop'` to create this column otherwise I was getting this error:

```
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique:
```

But with `duplicates='drop'`, I'm only getting a single value stored in all the cells. How do I fix this problem and store the actual quantile ranges for all the values?

PS: I tried creating a sample dataframe that would replicate this issue, but I wasn't able to create one where the above error was replicated.

Comment: Picture are poor medium to exchange textual data (code, data, error, etc.). Copy paste and format instead or provide a link to if data are to huge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples